# How to show images and load more if needed?

Tags: php, jquery, image, mysqli

I'm trying to make a script for PHP that loads 5 lines of images where 3 images on all lines are loaded and showed, however on the last one only 2 images are loaded and a image with "load more" appears. When You push it it loads the rest of images using jQuery.

I'm using MYSQLi to get the data however I do not know hot wo put it the way I described.
I appriciate any, seriously any help in that case!

Comment: any code whatsoever will help greatly here.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I know, but it's hard for me to write, that's why I'm asking for a little help :/  I'm trying to write it right now

Comment: i know its hard to write, but without knowing how what you are currently doing operates, there is no way a person could possibly help you with this. without code to work with, the best response you're going to get is people flaming you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more of theory, so I will give you theory steps.

1. Write a **PHP function** that will take **one integer parameter** (you may have more than one parameters based on your requirement)
2. This function should **returns 9 records**
3. Append a **load more icon to the list** of 9 and Load this records on the page
4. Write a jQuery function for Load-More Image **click event**
5. When user clicks on that icon, using **jQuery.Ajax()** function call the PHP function
6. here now pass a integer to **star number**
7. Since you are providing starting index, you will now get **next 9 records** from the function.
8. on **$.Ajax() success function**, append this new list to the div which is holding the images.

hope this theory will give you a start.

Comment: Thank you! It sure will help :)

Comment: if you think this is helpful you may want to consider either up-voting or accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the first three with an initial Database query; however if you can use JS and JQuery then you can always use an AJAX call to get the other 2 images on the event.

Essentially you get the first 3 images and display them, then you have a button below that says 'load more'. When that button is clicked, call a Javascript function that uses some AJAX to call a PHP script that will load the other images.

The (probably easier) other method is to get all the images at once, show your button that says 'load more' and hide the other 2 images. On click of that button show the other two images. something like

```
<div id="fristThree">
<img ... />
<img ... />
<img ... />
</div>
<div id="otherTwo">
<img ... />
<img ... />
<button> load more </button>
```

and in Jquery, just hide the 'otherTwo' div, then on button click, show it via jquery.

But I still would think AJAX is the preferred method.